# 'CGO_CFLAGS' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Tags: mingw-w64

I am getting an error while compiling make file using mingw64. I have already installed go in my system

```
C:\Users\geogi\Downloads\magicard-recover-master\magicard>mingw32-make makefile  windows
mingw32-make: Nothing to be done for 'makefile'.
CGO_CFLAGS="-I/include" CGO_LDFLAGS="-L/lib/Windows -Wl,--enable-stdcall-fixup,-rpath=/lib/Windows -lHCNetSDK" GOOS=windows CC=x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc CXX=x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ go build -ldflags "-s -w" -o build/Windows/magicard-recover.exe src/magicard-recover.go
'CGO_CFLAGS' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
mingw32-make: *** [Makefile:17: windows] Error 1

error " 'CGO_CFLAGS' is not recognized as an internal or external command "
```

I tried to install go but still issue not resolved. I have also added go to environment variables.

Comment: Is the command `mingw32-make makefile  windows` correct? Should it be `mingw32-make  windows`?

Comment: I am getting same error if remove makefile from this line.